# Password Verifier Issue

Tags: java

Edit: This is probably very bad code in the PasswordVerifier.Java

I'm doing a password verifier that checks if the entered password is at least 6 characters long, has an Uppercase letter, lowercase letter, and a digit.

I think I have the logistics of it somewhat correct, but for some reason my program isn't going to the next prompt. It asks me for my password and then hangs up and doesn't tell me whether my password is valid or not. I'm thinking that my for loops are correct so I don't know what my issue is.

PasswordVerifier.Java

```
import java.util.*;

public class PasswordVerifier{

    //field
    private static int MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6;

    //methods
    public static boolean isValid(String str){

        boolean valid = false;

        PasswordVerifier pass = new PasswordVerifier();

        if(pass.hasUpperCase(str)|| pass.hasLowerCase(str) || pass.hasDigit(str)){
            valid = true;
        }

        if (str.length() < 6){
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;

    }

    //UpperCase Boolean check
    private boolean hasUpperCase(String str){

        boolean valid = false;

        int i = 0;

        while (i < str.length()){
            if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))
            valid = true;
        }   
        i++;

        return valid;
    }

    //Lowercase Boolean Check
    private boolean hasLowerCase(String str){

        boolean valid = false;

        int i = 0;

        while (i < str.length()){
            if (Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i)))
            valid = true;
        }   
        i++;

        return valid;
    }

    //Number boolean check
    private boolean hasDigit(String str){

        boolean valid = false;

        int i = 0;

        while (i < str.length()){
            if ((Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))))
            valid = true;
        }   
        i++;

        return valid;

    }   

}
```

PasswordDemo.Java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PasswordDemo{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String input; //To hold the user's input

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Password");

            if (PasswordVerifier.isValid(input)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valid Password");
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "invalid Password, try again.");
            }           

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `while` loops never increment `i`, because you placed `i++` just past the end of the loop.  The result is an infinite loop and the "hanging" you describe.

E.g. replace

```
while (i < str.length()){
    if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))
    {
        valid = true;
        // Added break because we found an uppercase letter already.
        break;
    }
    i++;  // Inside the while loop.
}
```

You'll need to make a similar change to each of your `while` loops.

Additionally, if you want to enforce all 3 provisions, don't use the logical-OR operator `||`, use logical-and, `&&`:

```
if (pass.hasUpperCase(str) && pass.hasLowerCase(str) && pass.hasDigit(str)) {
    valid = true;
}
```

That will make sure that the password has an uppercase letter *and* it has a lowercase letter *and* it has a digit.

Comment: btw you can simple code `valid =  pass.hasUpperCase(str) && pass.hasLowerCase(str) && pass.hasDigit(str);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are counting i++ outside the while loop.
Put it in the while like this:

```
private boolean hasUpperCase(String str){

    boolean valid = false;

    int i = 0;

    while (i < str.length()){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)))
        valid = true;
        i++;
    }   

    return valid;
}
```

This is the problem in every while loop you got.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're making three passes through the password in order to verify the three character conditions - you can condense this down to one pass.  In addition, you're checking the password's length last - you should check this first, as it's the fastest condition to verify.

```
public static boolean isValid(String str) {
    if(str.length() < 6) return false;
    int i = 0;
    boolean hasDigit = false;
    boolean hasLower = false;
    boolean hasUpper = false;
    while(i < str.length() && !hasDigit && !hasLower && !hasUpper) {
        if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            hasDigit = true;
        } else if(Character.isLowerCase(str.charAt(i))) {
            hasLower = true;
        } else if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
            hasUpper = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return hasDigit && hasUpper && hasLower;
}
```

In your case the performance gain is probably negligible, but bear this in mind for the future when you may be dealing with more than three conditions and a string (or whatever) with a length much greater than six.